# Warning: move_uploaded_file (godaddy)

Tags: php, file-upload

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/P1_222.jpg): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\coinvoiture.com\httpdocs\annonces.php on line 423
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\Windows\Temp\phpF005.tmp' to 'images/P1_222.jpg' in
>   G:\PleskVhosts\coinvoiture.com\httpdocs\annonces.php on line 423

```
    $pid = mysqli_insert_id($co);

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*500; //100 kb
$path = "admin/images/"; // Upload directory
$count = 1;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {
        $name="P".$count."_".$pid.".jpg";     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name)) {
                    $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded files
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check for the folder permission if it has write permission.

Comment: Set permissions (chmod) on the destination folder (images) to 666.

Comment: change the permission of upload folder to 0777 or 0755 on godaddy

Comment: Why You say it is a godaddy problem? I can see windows paths. Are You running those files on Your local windows machine?

Comment: BTW You don't have to use the last `else {...}` statement. just execute the code which you have inside

Comment: I do but the same problem

Comment: thank you very much it's work i change permisssions folder

Comment: May I suggest you always use absolute file paths. You can use relative directories in absolute filepaths. i.e. if the 'upload directory' is a couple of directories above this script then use: `$path =  __DIR__ ."/../../admin/images/";` This will **always** target the directory that is relative to this script. To see the full path then just use the `realpath` function. i.e .`var_dump(realpath(__DIR__ ."/../../admin/images/"));`. These techniques work exactly the same on windows and linux.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist for that problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory